# An approach to do something vs. an approach to doing something

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What is the preferred way to express something like this:

> An approach to design a software system

(here design is a verb)

or

> An approach to design of a software system

(here design is a noun)

In other words, should word `approach` as a noun be used with an infinitive?

Comment: The text of the question doesn't seem to match the title.

Comment: Given the type of question you’ve asked, I think you might be interested in [our sister site for English Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).  ELL tends to be a better fit for these sorts of questions than ELU does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An approach to designing a software system

or

An approach to the design of a software system